# How to handle Flutter localized text with different number of placeholders for different locales?

Tags: flutter, intl, flutter-localizations

I'm using the intl_utils package. I have a localized text that accepts 2 placeholders in Japanese and 3 placeholders in English. When generating the files, error is thrown due to the mismatch. How to fix this?